# java read from network input stream with buffer(need to exclude emty symbols)

Tags: java, networking, java-io

I have method which reads from networked input stream.

```
    //pattern value is shell prompt string ":~#"
    //this do read shells output like from command "ls", etc...
    public String readUntil(String pattern) throws IOException, JSchException {
    long began = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    socket.setTimeout(timeout);
    iks: while (true) {
        try {
            int c = -1;
            byte[] text = new byte[1024];
            c = in.read(text);
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (c != -1) {
                sb.append(new String(text));
                lastTime = now;
            }
            if (now - lastTime > timeout){
                System.out.println( "BREAK BY TIMEOUT");
                break;
            }
            if (sb.toString().contains(pattern)) {
                System.out.println( "BREAK BY PATTERN");
                break;
            }
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("¬"+e);
            break iks;
        }
    }
    System.out.println( "TIME TAKEN readUntil -> "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-began));
    //Log.v("¬","result -> "+sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

this works reasonably fast, but every read fills end of byte array with null values. How to do "sb.append(new String(text));" excluding empty bytes?

Comment: Look, the Java API provides for the case that you need to read String data from an InputStream. Look up "Reader", in particular "InputStreamReader".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `BufferedInputStream` in your code -> `BufferedInputStream(InputStream in)`

And method `read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` reads bytes from this byte-input stream into the specified byte array, starting at the given offset, and returns the number of bytes read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached.

in your code it will be:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
...
byte text[] = new byte[]; // size of byte array can change
c = bis.read(text, 0, 1024);
```

Comment: This answers nothing and overlooks the real coding errors. Specifying all three parameters to read() like this just creates an opportunity to get the length wrong.

Comment: but when you read last bytes, and thay are less then 1024, you will read only this bytes, and text.lenght will < 1024. There will be not a single 0 at the end. Or i'm wrong?

Comment: That is correct, but it has nothing to do with my comment. Your code should be either `bis.read(text)` or `bis.read(text, 0, text.length)`, and it still doesn't answer the question. As a matter of fact using both a `byte[]` array *and* a `BufferedInputStream` is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Your reading logic is faulty, because you allocate a buffer of 1024 (all members initialized to null) and then at the last pass, clearly some part of the buffer can remain empty, resulting in null values written in.

So you need to stop reading once the end of stream has been reached, try changing your code along the lines of:

```
byte[] buff = new byte[255];

    String output = "";
    InputStream is = //get input stream

    int n = 0;
    while ( (n = is.read(buff) )!=-1)
    {
        output += new String(buff,0,n);
    }

    is.close();
```

That way you will get the string with only initialized buffer members, the value of "n" being the number of bytes actually read (=no nulls). You can change the read chunk as you like.